# Do windows services log why they wont start?

Tags: windows, dll, service

I have a windows service that will not start on a brand new windows server 2012 installation.

When I attempt to start the service, I get this error.

> The Foobar service on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs.

[image]

I come from a linux background, and don't use windows much. In my troubleshooting attempts, I have been able to gather the following logs.

```
The requested Performance Counter is not a custom counter, it has to be initialized as ReadOnly.\u000d\u000a   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter.InitializeImpl()\u000d\u000a   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter..ctor(String categoryName, String counterName, String instanceName, Boolean readOnly)\u000d\u000a   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter..ctor(String categoryName, String counterName, Boolean readOnly)\u000d\u000a   at foobar.sage.OnStart(String[]
```

Things that I have tried from the front page of google.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2081976/1626687

```
PS C:\Users\sowen> lodctr C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\CORPerfMonExt.dll
PS C:\Users\sowen> lodctr C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\CORPerfMonExt.dll
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14513897/1626687

```
PS C:\Users\sowen> unlodctr .NETFramework
Removing counter names and explain text for .NETFramework
Updating text for language 009PS 
PS C:\Users\sowen> lodctr 'C:\Windows\Inf\.NETFramework\corperfmonsymbols.ini'
```

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/46a21b31-f5fc-4a44-bd4c-c9884a923943/performance-monitor-in-windows-server-2012

Modify HKLM/\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Perflib
Disable Performance Counters  = 0

```
loadctl /r
```

None of these attempts have resolved the issue. Is there a place where windows shows additional logging why this service wont start?

Comment: Did you develop this software? Or was it developed by a 3rd party?

Comment: It was developed at my company a long time ago. The application is running on all existing servers, but won't run on a new server I'm creating.

Comment: Do you still have the source code? If you don't, it's not really a programming question and is more suited to [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: You are correct mason, moving to SF

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be much more you can do for logging besides looking at the event viewer.

I finally got this running by using InstallUtil instead of sc.exe

```
sc.exe create foobar obj= "example.com\\someuser" password= "correct-horse-battery-staple" binPath= c:\foobar.exe start= auto depends= "MSMQ"

sc.exe delete foobar

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe /user="example.com\someuser" /password="correct-horse-battery-staple" c:\foobar.exe
```