# Crash while using .net performance counters

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, windows-8.1, performancecounter

I am trying yo use .NET performance counter in my application. Here is code:

```
if (!PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists("Processor"))
{
    CounterCreationDataCollection CCDC = new CounterCreationDataCollection();

    // Add the counter.
    CounterCreationData NOI64 = new CounterCreationData();
    NOI64.CounterType = PerformanceCounterType.NumberOfItems64;
    NOI64.CounterName = "%Processor Time";
    CCDC.Add(NOI64);

    // Create the category.
    PerformanceCounterCategory.Create("Processor", "", PerformanceCounterCategoryType.SingleInstance, CCDC);
}
PerformanceCounter PC = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "%Processor Time", false);
PC.RawValue = 0;
```

When I execute this code, I get crash at `PerformanceCounter PC = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "%Processor Time", false);` mentioned below

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in System.dll
>
> Additional information: The requested Performance Counter is not a custom counter, it has to be initialized as ReadOnly.

I tried `using  lodctr` command also but It dint work as mentioned in [The requested Performance Counter is not a custom counter, it has to be initialized as ReadOnly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046741/the-requested-performance-counter-is-not-a-custom-counter-it-has-to-be-initiali)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what are you trying to achieve? It says clearly, that you should initialize it as read-only. So, according to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2b0byczf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you need to pass `true` and not `false` as the third parameter.

Also, don't assign zero to `RawValue` property. This is not going to work (since the counter is read-only).

Comment: awww...I really overlooked this parameter and did lot of troubleshooting in setting up performance counters. Thanks for your help...